# Can not host a webpage on Github

Tags: github, git-branch

I have a javascript and html snake game and I want to host it on github I do All the steps and make a gh-pages But I get this error 404 File not found ?when I search Username.github.io/repository-name 
Any idea why and how I can fix it? Should I wait for github email After I do the commands??

Comment: Go to your repository's settings page (`https://github.com/:user/:repo/settings`) and look under the **GitHub Pages** section. Does it say something like "Your site is published at user.github.io/repository"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most web servers have a "default" page, e.g. `index.html`, that will be shown when the user doesn't request a particular page. GitHub Pages is no different.

Your repository contains a single file called `snakeGame.html`, which [works just fine if you request it](http://peggykh.github.io/Snake/snakeGame.html). Unfortunately, GitHub Pages doesn't know that this page should be shown by default. As far as it knows that file has no special meaning.

To get your page to show up at `http://peggykh.github.io/Snake/` instead of `http://peggykh.github.io/Snake/snakeGame.html`, you should rename your file to `index.html`.